# how to filter using the user's role at user grid view?

Tags: php, yii, yii-extensions

How to filter the records using user's role at user grid view?

I am using yii-user extension. I am able to show user's role on user/admin gridview,but i can i use the filter on this? Here is my view:

```
   $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'user-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
    'filter'=>$model,
    'columns'=>array(
        array(
            'name' => 'id',
            'type'=>'raw',
            'value' => 'CHtml::link(CHtml::encode($data->id),array("admin/update","id"=>$data->id))',
        ),
        array(
            'name' => 'username',
            'type'=>'raw',
            'value' => 'CHtml::link(UHtml::markSearch($data,"username"),array("admin/view","id"=>$data->id))',
        ),
        array(
            'name'=>'email',
            'type'=>'raw',
            'value'=>'CHtml::link(UHtml::markSearch($data,"email"), "mailto:".$data->email)',
        ),
        'create_at',
        'lastvisit_at',
        /*array(
            'name'=>'superuser',
            'value'=>'User::itemAlias("AdminStatus",$data->superuser)',
            'filter'=>User::itemAlias("AdminStatus"),
        ),*/
        array(
            'name'=>'status',
            'value'=>'User::itemAlias("UserStatus",$data->status)',
            'filter' => User::itemAlias("UserStatus"),
        ),
        array(
            //'name'=>'assignments',
            'header'=>Rights::t('core', 'Roles'),
            'type'=>'raw',
            'value'=>function($data) {
                                        $roles = Rights::getAssignedRoles($data->id);
                                        foreach($roles as $role){
                                            $user_role=$role->name;
                                        }
                                         return $user_role;
                                    }
        ),
        array(
            'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
            'template'=>'{view}{delete}'
        ),
    ),
));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add filter like below:

```
array(
        //'name'=>'assignments',
        'header'=>Rights::t('core', 'Roles'),
        'type'=>'raw',
        'filter'=>CHtml::listData(Rights::model()->findAll(),'id','name'), //***
        'value'=>function($data) {
                                    $roles = Rights::getAssignedRoles($data->id);
                                    foreach($roles as $role){
                                        $user_role=$role->name;
                                    }
                                     return $user_role;
                                }
    ),
```

I assumed that `Rights` is a model and holds roles on it with `id`,`name`.

By the line that I indicated that with `***` in comments, Yii will generate a dropdown as a filter which shows roles name as option value and roles id as option value.

Comment: Not working. Getting this error "Call to undefined method Rights::model()"

Comment: @SRana As I said, I assumed that you have a model named `Rights`. Please replace it with your own model

Comment: I don't know which model would do this. Because i am using Yii-rights module